# Python. Pandas. CSV. Count mean by other column value

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following table:

```
Days, Age,  Sex

5,    39,   F

4,    54,   M

4,    26,   M

5,    42,   M

4,    29,   M
```

I want to count mean days for 2 groups: for those who are 35 and under and for those who are 36 and older. I was thinking about something like

```
df["Days"].mean().where(df["Age"]>35)......
```

The best ways I see the result is:

```
Age
Age <= 35   4
Age >= 35   4.6666
```

What will be the best command to do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df = (df['Days'].groupby(df["Age"]>35)
                .mean()
                .rename(index={True:'Age > 35', False:'Age <= 35'})
                .reset_index())
```

Or:

```
df["Age"] = np.where(df["Age"]>35,'Age > 35','Age <= 35')
df = df.groupby('Age', as_index=False)['Days'].mean()
print (df)
         Age      Days
0  Age <= 35  4.000000
1   Age > 35  4.666667
```

Comment: Thank you. For the second suggestion I get this error: cannot perform reduce with flexible type. Could you please tell the way to fix it?

Comment: @Jerry - it seems some bug, do you use last pandas/numpy versions? `pandas 0.22.0`. ?

Comment: What is `print (df['Days'].dtype)` ?

Comment: The type is
int64

Comment: Yes, and for the second it returns "invalid syntax", than I add ")" at very end and it returns "cannot perform reduce with flexible type"

Comment: hmmm, I changed second solution, can you check it?

Answer (score 2):

```
df.groupby(pd.cut(df['Age'], bins=[0, 35, np.inf]))['Days'].mean()
Out: 
Age
(0.0, 35.0]    4.000000
(35.0, inf]    4.666667
Name: Days, dtype: float64
```

Comment: They can be renamed but I don't think it's essential to the question.

Comment: Thank you. I have the output but for both lines I have NaN instead of numbers. Could you please tell the way to fix it? Shall I check the missing values?

Comment: Can you post the output of `df[['Age', 'Sex', 'Days']].head().to_dict()`?

Comment: Your Days columns is probably not numeric @Jerry.

Comment: {'Age': {0: 39, 1: 54, 2: 26, 3: 42, 4: 29},
 'Days': {0: 5, 1: 4, 2: 4, 3: 5, 4: 4},
 'Sex': {0: 'F', 1: 'M', 2: 'M', 3: 'M', 4: 'M'}}

Comment: Works! Thank you! I used characters not from English as headers, it solved when I renamed in English.